# Angular 2 User Input Tutorial

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-scope

I am trying to understand Angular JS 2. When I try the code mentioned in https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/user-input.html, I get a blank value inserted into the list after typing the text in input and hitting the enter key. Here is the ES5 I tried:

```
//ES5
function TodoList() {
  this.todos = ["Eat Breakfast", "Walk Dog", "Breathe"];
  this.addTodo = function(todo) {
    this.todos.push(todo.value);
  };
  this.doneTyping = function($event) {
    if($event.which === 13) {
      this.addTodo($event.target.value);
      $event.target.value = null;
    }
  }
}
TodoList.annotations = [
  new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
    selector: "todo-list"
  }),
  new angular.ViewAnnotation({
    template:
      '<ul>' +
      '<li *ng-for="#todo of todos">' +
      '{{ todo }}' +
      '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '<input #textbox (keyup)="doneTyping($event)">' +
      '<button (click)="addTodo(textbox.value)">Add Todo</button>',
    directives: [angular.NgFor]
  })
];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  angular.bootstrap(TodoList);
});
```

This exactly as mentioned in Angular.io/docs , has anyone else seen same issue? Is there an error in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, it is incorrect documentation in Angular JS 2. The code:

```
this.addTodo = function(todo) {
    this.todos.push(todo.value);
  };
```

should have been:

```
this.addTodo = function(todo) {
    this.todos.push(todo);
  };
```

as the value is passed to `addTodo` from `doneTyping` and also from `button`.